# Drupal 7 - what's involved in implementing AMP?

Tags: drupal, amp-html

I'd like to implement "Accelerated Mobile Pages" (AMP) for one content type (the website has 25) on my website.

I contract out my web development and I'm trying to scope out time/$ for this work - can anyone help with my questions:

- How complex is implementing AMP?
- How much time would it take generally?

Thanks

Comment: You may check this [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/amp) which is designed to convert Drupal pages into pages that comply with the [AMP standard](https://www.ampproject.org/). Here's another [tutorial](https://inviqa.com/blog/how-get-started-google-amp-drupal-7-and-drupal-8) which might also help.

Comment: Thanks but how complex is this a job as per my requirements and on average how long would it take?